# Upgrading Elasticsearch and Kibana running on Kubernetes from 7.12.0 to 7.17.10

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, elasticsearch-7, kibana-7

I am trying to upgrade my cluster to latest supported image and I am having issues.
According to [Elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/setup-upgrade.html)  I should be able to upgrade directly from any version between 7.0–7.16 to 7.17.10, yet when I tried that in my non-prod environment, the nodes showed the following in the logs:

> {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2023-06-14T11:51:56,132Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.s.a.RealmsAuthenticator", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "Authentication of [elastic] was terminated by realm [reserved] - failed to authenticate user [elastic]", "cluster.uuid": "****", "node.id": "*****" }
>
> {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2023-06-14T11:52:06,130Z", "level": "ERROR", "component": "o.e.x.s.a.e.ReservedRealm", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "failed to retrieve password hash for reserved user [elastic]", "cluster.uuid": "****", "node.id": "*****"

I didn't apply any changes in configuration, simply swapped the image version reference from 7.12.0 to 7.17.10 and that's what I got a few minutes later.

my elasticsearch.yml looks like this:

```
path.repo: /usr/share/elasticsearch/backup
path.logs: /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/elk
reindex.remote.whitelist: `["****, *****" ]`
http.max_content_length: 1000mb
xpack:
  security:
    enabled: true
    transport:
      ssl:
        enabled: true
        verification_mode: certificate
        key: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/tls.key
        certificate: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/tls.crt
        certificate_authorities:  /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/tls.crt
    http:
      ssl:
        enabled: true
        verification_mode: certificate
        key: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/tls.key
        certificate: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/tls.crt
        certificate_authorities:  /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/tls.crt
    authc: 
      realms:
        native:
          native1:
            order: 0
        oidc:
          oidc1:
            rp.client_id: ""
            rp.response_type: "code" 
            rp.requested_scopes: ["openid", "email", "profile"]
            rp.redirect_uri: "https://********/api/security/v1/oidc"
            op.issuer: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/****/v2.0" 
            op.authorization_endpoint: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/******/oauth2/v2.0/authorize" 
            op.token_endpoint: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/******/oauth2/v2.0/token" 
            op.userinfo_endpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo" 
            op.endsession_endpoint: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/******/oauth2/v2.0/logout" 
            rp.post_logout_redirect_uri: "https://******/logged_out" 
            op.jwkset_path: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/******/discovery/v2.0/keys" 
            claims.principal: email 
            claims.groups: groups
            claim_patterns.principal: "^([^@]+)@.*$"
xpack.monitoring.collection.interval: 600s
xpack.monitoring.collection.index.stats.timeout: 120s
xpack.monitoring.collection.node.stats.timeout: 120s
xpack.monitoring.collection.cluster.stats.timeout: 120s
indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 3000
```

Please let me know if more information is needed and if there's something wrong or missing with what I tried to do.

Comment: **If either the username or the password does not match with the saved credentials, the following logs will be generated.** You need to enter the correct username and password that should match with the credentials that you have set while setting the built-in user password. If by any chance you’ve forgotten the password, you can reset the password by following the steps mentioned in this [post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/x-pack-authentication-issue/121632/6).

Comment: If you have the sudo access, try to create a system user using [file based auth](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/file-realm.html) then re-create other system users with the same password then revert the access type to normal login that may work for you.

Comment: Have you tried the above comments and it helped you to resolve your  issue?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I've checked what are the used username and password and they do match with the saved credentials. And regarding the other suggestion, I am unable to post any API commands. Getting 'Empty reply from server'.

Comment: Did you change the password for the elastic use recently? If so, it looks like something is using the old password.

Comment: Disable the security configuration (in case you are in your home network or safe network). I mean check by disabling and running the ES followed by **./bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive** command to set new passwords, then you can enable the security functions as well. Try by disabling only a few of the security configurations at first. If it doesn't work, then you have to disable all security functions.

Comment: Haven't changed the password recently and when I try to run the ./bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive I get an unauthorized error about user 'elastic'.
Also when I try to disable the security functions I get an SSL/TLS error in the logs, assuming you're referring to xpack.security.

Comment: As per [Setting built-in user passwords](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/built-in-users.html#set-built-in-user-passwords) - "After you set a password for the elastic user, the bootstrap password is no longer valid; you cannot run the elasticsearch-setup-passwords command a second time". So It seems this is expected.
Also refer to similar [issue 1](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/failed-to-retrieve-password-hash-for-reserved-user-kibana/193592/5) and [issue 2](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/authentication-of-elastic-was-terminated-by-realm-reserved/275072/4).

Comment: Can you check the default user password[elastic] first, the easiest way is to try to login to GUI with the password you are trying. Hope you're following the steps of the X-Pack Authentication issue ? If so, I would suggest following up on the thread or create a new thread with an ES support forum.